# Watch for commits to a file

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is there any notification at all (Email, Text, Message-On-Screen, colored text, anything) that can tell me if a specific file has been committed?

For example: If a developer commits changes to the `Web.Config`, or to `Source/Lawls/CrazySauce.js`, what options do I have to bring that to my attention?

At the very least, something Pull-Request related would be okay.  Though I'm not always the one approving/merging.  At best, an email or automatic Jira ticket or something would be great.

Comment: What Git server are you using?

Comment: Almost 5 years later, did you ever find a way? With BitBucket?

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets I don't know this moment, but at the time I discovered that this was only possible with BitBucket Server, not Cloud.  The best bet is writing a custom service that listens to webhooks and manually reviews files, then does whatever you want based on your rules.

Answer (score 3):

Bitbucket (like GitHub and other git hosting providers) supports [webhooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html), a feature that will make a `POST` request to a URL of your choice whenever certain actions occur on your repository.

It would be fairly easy to write a simple server that would receive a webhook and perform some sort of notification.

Note that based on [the content of the push notification](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html#EventPayloads-Push), the list of modified files isn't available to your directly.  You would need to consume the information from the webhook and then do something to get the list of files in the selected commit: for example, by maintaining a local clone of the repository, updating it, and using that to get information about which files were modified.

Comment: I know it's been a day or two since you answered, but I wanted to say: I was already down this path when I asked the question and, if I were already manually querying the repo (either because I was pulling, or comparing, or web crawling or whatever), then the webhook sort of loses value anyway.  While I think you're right that this is (or was?) the best bet, it's essentially saying "No, you can't, program your own."  That's why I hadn't marked it as the answer.  Though I did up-vote it.  I still think it would be great if somebody answered.  Also, 1,000+ views and not many upvotes, lol.